# How to get the internal name of a Person/Group?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I have a Person/Group column named PERSON. This is its structure.

person

---

fullname

address

e-mail

---

when I check its internal name, person appears. now, i'm creating a flow with the **get-items** action with a **filter query**.

the query is 'PersonFullName' eq person but it doesn't return anything. Upon testing other queries, it seems that I need to access the internal name equivalent of "person full name" but the only internal name I see is "person".
 My question is how do I access the "fullname" of person?

Comment: Please update question with error or more details..

Comment: hi, sorry! fixed it already.

Comment: You can get the internal name from column settings from list settings.